# Using log4j 1.2's HTMLLayout class over log4j 2

Tags: log4j, log4j2

I am using log4j 2.0 for logging my application. But the new log4j 2.0 api don't let us edit the HTMLLayout.it is defined as final class.Another thing,  it has the log4j 1.2 api in it.So can ı achieve the extending HTMLLayout  using log4j 1.2 api on log4j 2.0 ?If I can, I will customize the html log file as I want.

Comment: Please take a look on https://stackoverflow.com/a/29678957/977855

Answer (score 0):

The question points out that the log4j 2 HtmlLayout class is final, so how can the layout be customized?

The answer is that it cannot without changes to the log4j API. Such changes need to be requested in a Log4j forum.

You'll need to file a feature request in the log4j issue tracker. Requests with patches have the best chance of being addressed quickly.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question.

Comment: I disagree. This does answer the question. The question points out that the log4j 2 HtmlLayout class is final, so how can the layout be customized? The answer is that it cannot without changes to the log4j API. Such changes need to be requested in a Log4j forum.

Comment: Please take a look on stackoverflow.com/a/29678957/977855